# VBS launch a batch which set the environement variables

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, environment-variables

- I have a batch file which set my environment variables : setenv.bat
- I want to use setenv.bat in a VB Script in order to set my variables

To sum up, my VBS launches setenv.bat, then it uses the environment variables specified in setenv.bat.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Aphoria is right. When you run a batch file from a VBS, a separate copy of `cmd` is started, which means the batch file is executed in its own environment. That environment is lost as soon as the batch file (or, more precisely, the `cmd` process running that batch) terminates. Thus, any variable assignments made by that batch file turn out "local" to it.

That doesn't mean, however, that you can't achieve what you want at all. You need a way to assign values that preserves them across different `cmd` sessions. And there *is* a command that does that, and it's `SETX`. It allows you to create/modify a "global" environment variable, one that persists not only across different `cmd` sessions, but across Windows sessions as well.

The command's syntax is similar to that of `SET`, only there's no `=` character between the variable name and its value:

```
SETX variable value
```

If the value contains spaces (or special characters), enclose it in double quotes (note that they are removed when the value gets assigned). There are options to `SETX`, which you can learn from reading the built-in help, just run `SETX /?` at the command prompt, but this should be enough for your case.

One other thing about `SETX`, which doesn't really seem relevant in your situation but may still be worth keeping in mind for the future, is that, strangely enough, the assignment made by `SETX` isn't reflected in the `cmd` session where the assignment took place. (In fact, it isn't reflected in any cmd session active at the time.) That is, applying to your situation, you won't be able to read the new values in the same batch file that assigns them using `SETX`. But you will certainly be able to read them in your VBS after running (and waiting for the completion of) the batch file.

So, here's a test setup for demonstrating how this works:

- `setenv.bat`:

  ```
  SETX testvar1 123
  ```
- `test.vbs`:

  ```
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objUserEnv = objShell.Environment("User")

  ' show the value before running the batch script
  WScript.Echo "1. testvar1=" & objUserEnv("testvar1")

  ' set the environment with the batch file
  objShell.Run "setenv.bat", 1, true

  ' show the value again to see the effect
  WScript.Echo "2. testvar1=" & objUserEnv("testvar1")
  ```

**UPDATE**

If some of your variables are being *undefined* (or *deleted*, as in `SET variable=`) as part of `setenv.bat`, this is how you do that using `SETX`:

```
SETX variable ""
```

Comment: You are right about `SETX`. The only caveat is that `SETX` cannot delete environment variables, AFAIK. If you don't want the environment variables hanging around permanently, you will have to delete the from the registry. You could use `REG.EXE` or have the VB Script do it.

Comment: You are correct about deleting. The help doesn't state how to do it and my admittedly brief research didn't turn anything up. I did notice on Windows 7, that `SETX` didn't work unless I ran my command prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

No, this will not work. When your VB Script runs `setevn.bat`, the .bat file runs in its own process, so any environment variables you set won't be accessible by your VB Script.

Can you do it the other way? Call your VB Script from your .bat file?

Comment: To the person who downvoted me, did you actually test this? I did and my answer stands. If I'm wrong, please show me how.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't call my VBS inside my bat. I will find another way to do it. Thanks a lot to both for your answers.

Comment: If this answer (or another) answered your question, please upvote and accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access any environmental variables, with the exclution of the 'psudo-environmental variables like %time% and %date%.

I've created a batch file and a vbs file that interact:

`k.bat`

```
@echo off

:: Setting ERRORLEVEL to 0
DIR *.* > NUL

:: Display current ErrorLevel
echo ErrorLevel=%errorlevel%

:: Creating a variable for the VBS file to see
set VBS=Can you see me?

echo.
echo Entering VBS
echo =============================
cscript /nologo k.vbs
echo =============================
echo Exited VBS
echo.

echo ErrorLevel=%errorlevel%
echo Test=%Test%
echo Test2=%Test2%
ECHO VBS=%VBS%
goto :eof
```

`k.vbs`

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

' Store the EV %PATH% in var1
var1 = "PATH = " & wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%PATH%" )

' Print var1
wscript.echo var1
wscript.echo

' Getting Ready to Create / Set an EV (In Vista and Above you cannot 
' set "SYSTEM" variables.
Set wshUserEnv = wshShell.Environment( "USER" )
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment( "SYSTEM" )

' Another method of retrieving an EV that takes advantage of wshShell.Environment
' Get value of %Test%
WScript.Echo "Test=" & wshUserEnv( "Test" )

' Set EV %Test%
wshUserEnv( "Test" ) = "VBS Can set Environmental Variables"

' Print out the value of %Test%
WScript.Echo "Test=" & wshUserEnv( "Test" )

'Both methods are not created equilly
WScript.Echo "1 VBS=" & wshUserEnv( "VBS" )
wscript.echo "2 VBS = " & wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%VBS%" )

' Overwrite %VBS%
wshUserEnv( "VBS" ) = ""

WScript.Echo "3 VBS=" & wshUserEnv( "VBS" )
WScript.Echo "4 VBS=" & wshSystemEnv( "VBS" )
wscript.echo "5 VBS = " & wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%VBS%" )


' In Vista and up, VBS cannot delete an EV it did not create
wshUserEnv.Remove( "VBS" )

' Delete Variable %Test%
wscript.echo "Deleting Test"
wshUserEnv.Remove( "Test" )

' Show variable %Test% again, using first method
wscript.echo "TEST = " & wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%Test%" )
WScript.Echo "Test=" & wshUserEnv( "Test" )

' Create one last varible for the batch file to check
wshUserEnv( "Test2" ) = "Yes you can!"
WScript.Echo "Test2=" & wshUserEnv( "Test2" )

' Set the ERRORLEVEL to 99
wscript.quit 99
```

My Output (I've clipped much of the %PATH%, but it does display property.)

`Output:`

```
VBS=
ErrorLevel=0
VBS= 2:39:46.02

Entering VBS
=============================
PATH = c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE;c
 Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.
tudio 9.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\
 Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
Shell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;
d++\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll;C:\Prog
indows NT\Accessories\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Pr
w64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;D:\Program F

Test=
Test=VBS Can set Environmental Variables
1 VBS=
2 VBS =  2:39:46.02
3 VBS=
4 VBS=
5 VBS =  2:39:46.02
Deleting Test
TEST = %Test%
Test=
Test2=Yes you can!
=============================
Exited VBS

ErrorLevel=99
Test=
Test2=
VBS= 2:39:46.02
```

So, as you can see, a batch file can use Environmental Variables to send data to a VBS script, and the script can read and act on those variables. But, with the exception of the `%ERRORLEVEL%`, the VBS script cannot change or add variables for the batch file to see and use.

This is because the VBS script is launched with a **copy** of the environment used by the batch file, so when it returns control to the calling batch file, that environment dies and the variables in the original environment were never altered. (Again, with the exception of `%ERRORLEVEL%`.)

Comment: That's all great, but it's not what the OP asked for. He wants to run his VB Script and have it call `setevn.bat` and then access the environment vars set in the batch file, which is not possible.